# Using 'Any' and 'AnyObject' types in Swift Linux gives errors

Tags: swift, linux, perfect

I have this line of code:

`produceJSONMessage(message: message as AnyObject)`

That works ok in XCode (Mac). However building it in linux using `swift build` produces an error:

```
/home/ubuntu/x/x/objects.swift:x:x: error: 'Any' is not convertible to 'AnyObject'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

produceJSONMessage(message: message as AnyObject)
```

So I followed its advice by using `produceJSONMessage(message: message as! AnyObject)`. It doesn't throw an error during build, but it crashes during runtime with:

`Could not cast value of type 'Any' (0x9aab88) to 'Swift.AnyObject' (0x7f7c84007c88).`

Anyway I got it to build and not throw an error with:

`produceJSONMessage(message: message as? AnyObject)`

The new problem is that when the function receives the object, it is always nil (it is not nil before entering the function). This is the function signature:

`func produceJSONMessage(message: AnyObject? = nil)`

Where `message` is usually a of String:Any type or a plain String

Anything that I should take note of here? All combinations of the codes I posted work fine for Mac XCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by removing `AnyObject` from my code above and replacing them with `Any`. Maybe I misused the `AnyObject` type, but it didn't help that it built ok in Mac but not in Linux!